# Eloquent Query Building

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I would like to know how can i transform this query into eloquent. Im having some troubles displaying those "counts" fields.

```
$resultados = DB::select( DB::raw("
    Select * From (
    Select
        P.*,
        count(distinct PP.id) as countProduct,
        count(distinct C.id) as countCity,
        count(distinct CO.id) as countCountry,
        count(distinct CON.id) as countContinent
    From
        packages P
        Inner join citie_package CP
            on P.id = CP.package_id
        Inner join cities C
            on CP.city_id = C.id
        Inner Join countries CO
            on C.country_id = CO.id
        Inner join continents CON
            on CO.continent_id = CON.id
        Inner Join product_package PP
            on P.id = PP.package_id
    where
       $whereCondition
    group by
        P.id,
        P.name,
        P.image,
        P.days,
        P.operator_id,
        P.badge,
        P.price,
        P.brochure,
        P.lodging,
        P.itinerary,
        P.services,
        P.observations,
        P.offer,
        P.featured,
        P.validity,
        P.created_at,
        P.updated_at,
        P.invisible,
        P.operationdates
        ) as pepe
    where
      $subWhereCondition


"));
```

For now the query is working good (on my localhost), when i uploaded it to production i found the following problem:

"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.

So im deciding to built it again but on this time using eloquent.

Thanks!!

Edit:

Before i tried something like this:

```
$resultado = DB::table('packages')
    ->join('product_package','packages.id','=','product_package.package_id')
    ->join('products','products.id','=','product_package.product_id')
    ->join('citie_package','packages.id','=','citie_package.package_id')
    ->join('cities','cities.id','=','citie_package.city_id')
    ->join('countries','countries.id','=','cities.country_id')
    ->join('continents','continents.id','=','countries.continent_id')
    ->where(function($resultado) use ($input){
        if(isset($input['products'])){
            $resultado->whereIn('products.id',$input['products']);
        }
        if(isset($input['cities'])){
            $resultado->whereIn('cities.id',$input['cities']);
        }
        if(isset($input['countries'])){
            $resultado->whereIn('countries.id',$input['countries']);
        }
        if(isset($input['continents'])){
            $resultado->whereIn('continents.id',$input['continents']);
        }
        if(isset($input['operator'])){
            $resultado->whereIn('packages.operator_id',$input['operator']);
        }
    })
    ->where('days', '>=', $input['durationFrom'])
    ->where('days', '<=', $input['durationTo'])
    ->where('price', '>=', str_replace('$','',str_replace('.','',$input['costFrom'])))
    ->where('price', '<=', str_replace('$','',str_replace('.','',$input['costTo'])))
```

->select(
array(
        DB::raw('packages.*'),
        DB::raw('COUNT(distinct cities.id) as `count`')
    )
)->get()
    return $resultado;

Using groupBy!

Finally i figured it out :D:

This is the final code

```
    $resultados = Package::
    join('product_package','packages.id','=','product_package.package_id')
    ->join('products','products.id','=','product_package.product_id')
    ->join('citie_package','packages.id','=','citie_package.package_id')
    ->join('cities','cities.id','=','citie_package.city_id')
    ->join('countries','countries.id','=','cities.country_id')
    ->join('continents','continents.id','=','countries.continent_id')
    ->where(function($resultado) use ($input){
        if(isset($input['products'])){
            $resultado->whereIn('products.id',$input['products']);
        }
        if(isset($input['cities'])){
            $resultado->whereIn('cities.id',$input['cities']);
        }
        if(isset($input['countries'])){
            $resultado->whereIn('countries.id',$input['countries']);
        }
        if(isset($input['continents'])){
            $resultado->whereIn('continents.id',$input['continents']);
        }
        if(isset($input['operator'])){
            $resultado->whereIn('packages.operator_id',$input['operator']);
        }
    })
    ->groupBy('packages.id')
    ->where('days', '>=', $input['durationFrom'])
    ->where('days', '<=', $input['durationTo'])
    ->where('price', '>=', str_replace('$','',str_replace('.','',$input['costFrom'])))
    ->where('price', '<=', str_replace('$','',str_replace('.','',$input['costTo'])))
    ->select( array(
            DB::raw('packages.*'),
            DB::raw('COUNT(distinct cities.id) as CountCity ,COUNT(distinct continents.id) as CountContinent, COUNT(distinct countries.id) as CountCountry, COUNT(distinct products.id) as CountProduct') ) )
    ->get();

if(isset($input['cities'])) {
    $resultados = $resultados->filter(function ($resultado) use ($input) {
        return $resultado->CountCity == count($input['cities']);
    });
}

if(isset($input['countries'])) {
    $resultados = $resultados->filter(function ($resultado) use ($input) {
        return $resultado->CountCountry == count($input['countries']);
    });
}

if(isset($input['continents'])) {
    $resultados = $resultados->filter(function ($resultado) use ($input) {
        return $resultado->CountContinent == count($input['continents']);
    });
}

if(isset($input['products'])) {
    $resultados = $resultados->filter(function ($resultado) use ($input) {
        return $resultado->CountProduct == count($input['products']);
    });
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. You say that the query is working but then show an error message indicating that the query is *not* working. Please edit your question and make it more clear.

Comment: Done! Sorry i missed some details!

Comment: No problem. It makes more sense now and hopefully someone here will be able to help.

Comment: What Eloquent code have you tried so far / where did you get to?